# Angular2 forms reloads instead of calling onSubmit()

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular2 is treating it like a normal form and does nothing:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value, $event)" #f="ngForm">
<md-card-title>Settings</md-card-title>
<md-card-content>
  <p>
    <md-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" required placeholder="Username"
              #name="ngModel"></md-input>
  </p>
</md-card-content>
<md-card-actions>
  <button [disabled]="!f.form.valid" type="submit" md-raised-button color="accent">Save</button>
</md-card-actions>
```

I included `disableDeprecatedForms()` and `provideForms()` to my bootstrap file and the disable function of the button works fine, but when I click it the function isn't working but the site is reloading...

Answer (score 1):

onSubmit() method may throw JavaScript error. Open the web browser developer tools and check for errors. In my case, I was trying to set a value to a property without setter in the onSubmit() method therefore upon execution the JavaScript throws error and the submit default form action has executed instead, and refreshed the page.

Comment: How do you recommend avoiding this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement onSubmit function in your component.
[Component onSubmit function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owA2h.png)
[Soruce](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)